# Lazy adapter only on scroll

Tags: android, image, listview, lazy-loading

Please excuse my english... I'm French :)

I write this post because I have a little problem with my Android application !
I have got a listview, with images and text, and I want to load images ONLY when the user see the items.

**For example**:

- We have got 1000 items in the listview
- User scroll and display item 52 to item 57.
- I want to load images for thoses items
- I want to unload (to free memory) other items

Am I clear ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a custom listview adapter you have a lot of examples in internet, for example: [asynchronous image listview](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/) or [multithreading-for-performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) or the thread: [Load asynchronous images in listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933783/load-asynchronous-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Use a lazyLoader as suggested by others. Additionally, use a gesture detector/listener. Don't call getImage/Bitmap methods of ImageLoaders for getting the images when the user flings.

**How can you do this ?** 
Set a boolean in onFling of the gesture listener method, and reset it accordingly.

**What do you achieve?**
When the user performs a fling operation, you skip downloading images.

**Alternative**
Accumulate requests and download after a delay of say 700 ms. Use a FIFO collection and the max size of the collection will be equal to the number of items visible. Reset(further delay) the download request if the user scrolls.

I prefer the 1st approach. Will post some code if I get time.

Comment: It would be great if you could show me a piece of code ! I will try the first approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the concept of lazyLoader
as u had to add jar file of lazy loader too

in listview there is property as
smoothscroll set it true.